# R reticulate on M1 Mac OSX

Tags: r, reticulate

Python 3.11.3 and R4.3.0

Upon loading any package, already installed via py_install or pip on the terminal, I get this weird error. I don't even know where to start. Somehow rpytools doesn't seem to work.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/library/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 119, in _find_and_load_hook
```